# How to relate objects by name and column

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am in doubt about the following situation, so please, check the following array of objects:

```
 let arrayQualityRated = [{
     name: "Jande",
     col: 4
 }, {
     name: "Good",
     col: 4
 }, {
     name: "Good",
     col: 4
 }, {
     name: "Bad",
     col: 4
 }, {
     name: "Elmo",
     col: 2
 }, {
     name: "Bad",
     col: 2
 }, {
     name: "Tiago",
     col: 3
 }, {
     name: "Bad",
     col: 3
 }];
```

I want to do some like filter based on the ***name*** and ***col*** keys.

But I need to do dynamically, so from what I understand, look for the keys "name" based on the following array:

```
let persons = ["Jande", "Elmo", "Tiago"]
```

I hope I have been clear about my doubt. I'm counting on your patience and help! :)

I expect output like that:

```
[   
    {
        name: "Jande",
        col: 4
    },
    {
        name: "Good",
        col: 4
    },
    {
        name: "Bad",
        col: 4
    },
    {
        name: "Good",
        col: 4
    }

],

[   
    {
        name: "Elmo",
        col: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Bad",
        col: 2
    }

],

[   
    {
        name: "Tiago",
        col: 3
    },
    {
        name: "Bad",
        col: 3
    }

]
```

Briefly, I want an individual array of objects based on the string "person name" (that based in array "persons") and "col".

Comment: *"array "Jande" and col "4""* You must mean **or** rather than **and**, since you have entries there where the name isn't "Jande".

Comment: I believe there is some inconsistency. What do you mean by array **"Jande" and col "4" >** ? Is that AND or OR ?

Comment: What i understood by **array "Jande" and col "4" >** is that either the name should be Jande or the col should be 4. Am i right?

Comment: it was actually just a comment ...I changed the output to see if it gets more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not a simple filter, as the result is expected in three different arrays. I'd use **map()** and then **filter()**, as the **col** value is dynamic (can't tell before you identify the person by name).

Have a look at the resulting array - it has the structure you were asking for.

```js
let arrayQualityRated = [{
  name: "Jande",
  col: 4
}, {
  name: "Good",
  col: 4
}, {
  name: "Good",
  col: 4
}, {
  name: "Bad",
  col: 4
}, {
  name: "Elmo",
  col: 2
}, {
  name: "Bad",
  col: 2
}, {
  name: "Tiago",
  col: 3
}, {
  name: "Bad",
  col: 3
}];

let persons = ["Jande", "Elmo", "Tiago"]

const classifyArrayItems = (persons, arrayQualityRated) => {
  // mapping the array, so it has all the persons
  return persons.map(person => {
    // first find the col number corresponding to the
    // person in the array
    const col = arrayQualityRated.find(e => e.name === person).col
    // return all the objects that have the same
    // col value
    return arrayQualityRated.filter(e => e.col === col)
  })
}

console.log(classifyArrayItems(persons, arrayQualityRated))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array.filter

```
var nameArr = ...;
var col = ...;
var found = arrayQualityRated.filter(function() {
  return name.indexOf(this.name) != -1 && this.col === col;
});
```

Comment: You've been tricked by the OP. :-) They said "and" but their example results show they mean "or".

Comment: (No need for those `()` around the return value.)